# Unable to start a java process using a gitlab ci pipeline to deploy on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, devops, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

What I'm trying to do is to deploy a `java` application on an `ec2` instance using `gitlab-ci` pipeline.
After copying the `.jar` file it has to start the process.

The deploy steps are the next ones:

```
*deploy:
  stage: 'deploy'
  image: ubuntu
  before_script:
    - apt update
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  script:
    - scp -r -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no target/file.jar user@ip:/home/ubuntu/jars
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@ip "sudo pkill -f file.jar"
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@ip "sudo nohup java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Xms100m -Xmx150m /home/ubuntu/jars/file.jar > /home/ubuntu/jars/file.log 2>&1 &"*
```

In the end the job has `success` status, but it is not starting the process.

Do you have any ideas how I can fix this issue?

Log:

```
 $ scp -r -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no target/file.jar ubuntu@ip:/home/ubuntu/jars
 Warning: Permanently added 'ip' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
 $ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@ip "sudo ps -ef | grep java"
 root      9781     1  1 11:15 ?        00:00:27 java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Xms100m -Xmx150m /home/ubuntu/jars/file.jar
 ubuntu    9991  9990  0 11:41 ?        00:00:00 bash -c sudo ps -ef | grep java
 ubuntu    9993  9991  0 11:41 ?        00:00:00 grep java
 $ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@ip "sudo pkill -f file.jar"
 $ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@ip "sudo nohup java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Xms100m -Xmx150m /home/ubuntu/jars/file.jar > /home/ubuntu/jars/file.log 2>&1 &"
 $ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@ip "cd /home/ubuntu/jars; ls"
 job
 file.jar
 file.log
Running after_script
Saving cache
Uploading artifacts for successful job
 Job succeeded
```

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace or error you are getting ?

Comment: yes, I have added it in the post

Comment: How do you know it's not starting the process?  What's in `file.log`?

Comment: I m connecting manually to the server and check the file.log and the last lines look like this:
2020-04-10 11:41:40.063   --- [       Thread-3]  - Shutdown initiated...
2020-04-10 11:41:40.100   --- [       Thread-3]  - Shutdown completed.

Comment: attach full `file.log` pls

Answer (score 0):

Update!
Using this command it worked perfect!

```
 - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@ip "sudo su root -c 'nohup java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Xms100m -Xmx150m /home/ubuntu/jars/file.jar > /home/ubuntu/jars/file.log 2>&1 &'"
```